# Swift 2.0 core data saves only one input in tableview

Tags: swift

http://www.raywenderlich.com/85578/first-core-data-app-using-swift

By this tutorial everything works, except that when in tableview when i type new name to save to coredata (i have save - add button)it stores only one value and tableview reads only one value - one cell, when i type multiple names to show in 3 or 4 cells, that does not work, core data won't save, it displays only previous typed name and i can't save any other  or new name in core data.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

//var names = [String]()
var people = [NSManagedObject]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    title = "\"The List\""
    tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self,
        forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func addName(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "New name",
        message: "Add a new name",
        preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save",
        style: .Default) { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in

            let textField = alert.textFields![0]
            self.saveName(textField.text!)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel",
        style: .Default) { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
    }

    alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler {
        (textField: UITextField!) -> Void in
    }

    alert.addAction(saveAction)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)

    presentViewController(alert,
        animated: true,
        completion: nil)

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return people.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    cellForRowAtIndexPath
    indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell =
        tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")


        let person = people[indexPath.row]
        cell!.textLabel!.text = person.valueForKey("name") as? String

        return cell!
}

func saveName(name: String) {
    //1
    let appDelegate =
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    //2
    let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Person",
        inManagedObjectContext:
        managedContext)

    let person = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!,
        insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedContext)

    //3
    person.setValue(name, forKey: "name")

    4
  //        var error: NSError?
  //        if !managedContext.save(&error) {
 //            print("Could not save \(error), \(error?.userInfo)")
 //        }  
    //5
    people.append(person)
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    //1
    let appDelegate =
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    //2
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Person")

    //3
    //let error: NSError?



    var fetchedResults : [NSManagedObject]?

    do {
        fetchedResults = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [NSManagedObject]
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    if let results = fetchedResults {
        people = results
    } else {
        //print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
    }
}
}
```